# Mail not sent in php pear mail package

Tags: php, pear

I am trying to use PEAR Mail to send from my gmail address using below code,

```
<?php
include("Mail.php");
echo "This test mail for authentication";
try{
$from_name = "Test";
$to_name = "from name"; 
$subject = "hai"; 
$mailmsg = "Happy morning";



$From = "From: ".$from_name." <frommail@gmail.com>"; 
$To = "To: ".$to_name." <tomail@gmail.com>"; 

$recipients = "tomail@gmail.com"; 
$headers["From"] = $From; 
$headers["To"] = $To; 
$headers["Subject"] = $subject; 
$headers["Reply-To"] = "gunarsekar@gmail.com"; 
$headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain"; 

$smtpinfo["host"] = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
$smtpinfo["port"] = "25"; 
$smtpinfo["auth"] = true; 
$smtpinfo["username"] = "mymail@gmail.com"; 
$smtpinfo["password"] = "mypassword"; 
//$smtpinfo["debug"]=True;
$mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo); 

$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $mailmsg); 

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}

}catch(Exception $e){
echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
echo "<br>Fin";
?>
```

this code not return any error or warning , it simply shows "Message successfully sent!" 
but, mail not receiver to mail the address.

can any one please tell what problem in mycode or what actually happening.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I see is that you have a mistake:  Your check checks against an variable called `$mail`, but everything else refers to `$mail_object`.  If that's in your actual code, then I'm guessing that might be part of it.

Some basic checks:

- Did you check to make sure that you have POP or IMAP enabled in Gmail?
- Have you set up this account with the same username and password on a normal machine, to ensure you can send and receive email outside of PHP?
- Verify that you can even talk to the GMail server (that it isn't blocked for some reason) by pinging `smtp.gmail.com` or using telnet to open a connection to port 25: `telnet smtp.gmail.com 25`
- [Read over the Gmail help for sending email.](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775)

Beyond that, it [looks like GMail requires TLS or SSL](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287), which means you have to use port `587` or port `465`.  I don't know if that package can handle encrypted connections, though.  (Even on port `25`, GMail requires SSL encryption.)  That may preclude this from working at all.

Comment: i change the port number as 465, It takes to much time to execute it means it loads more than 5 min , but it render only before mail function, i put some echo after mail function it not displayed in browser, still mail not received